# Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones. I really don't know how to solve this problem

Tags: rigging

I am new at blender and i have this problem. Sorry if there is an easy solution. I tried clear meshes and many other things but nothing works/ Tell me if you need other screenshots
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Type 'bone heat weight' (without the quotes) into the "Search on Blender" field at the top of this page and you'll  find that this question has been asked and answered many times before! There are also links on the right-hand side of this page titled "Related" which take you to similar questions.